# see a strange php exception in a springboot application

Tags: spring-boot

I recently deployed a spring boot application on google cloud compute engine and I see the below error during deployment. The application started fine and everything else works perfectly. Is it a known issue or how can I investigate into this. I looked online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736540/spring-security-deployed-app-on-aws-thinkphp-request) and there were no clear actions. How do I proceed to make sure that my application is safe from this vulnerability.

```
2021-02-28 15:41:11.249  INFO 9385 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.
```

Dependency tree: I looked for `php` related dependencies but couldn't find any.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ assessments ---
[INFO] com.lte.assessment:assessments:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.3-groovy-2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.15:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.spockframework:spock-spring:jar:1.3-groovy-2.4:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.25.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:runtime
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.16:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.18:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator:jar:2.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-metadata:jar:2.4.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0-m1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.4-7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
```

Comment: Something is calling your application with that URL. The parsing fails because it contains illegal chars. So you won't find the solution in your dependencies but you need to figure out what is calling youra pp with that URL.

Comment: could be anything right? But how to make sure that the application is not impacted?

Comment: It isn't that is quite clear from the exception. It is just an external process (looks like some monitoring or the like) calling your service with that URL, and that URL contains invalid chars.